# Merging content control documents into other content control documents without losing data

Tags: c#, openxml, office-2010

Ok, I think this is a relatively simple problem which is why I'm so surprised that after three days of searching I haven't been able to find a solution to.

What I'm trying to do is create one massive docx document from multiple sub-documents - all of which have data entered into content controls on their respective template documents.  Currently I have the sub-documents being created correctly and all their data being entered just as it should be.  Then, the completed sub-documents are each entered into specific content controls on the "master" template document.  The master document is being populated by the sub-documents correctly, however the data that was previously in the sub-documents' content controls is now gone.

How can I merge documents with data added to a custom XML part bound to content controls into another document without losing that bound data?

I'm using OpenXML 2 and C#.

NOTE: This is using the altChunk method, though I have also tried DocumentBuilder and gotten the same results.

Comment: Are you talking about docx or xlsx document?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'd mentioned that.  Its docx.

Comment: Edited the post to include docx and v2.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/02/05/move-insert-delete-paragraphs-in-word-processing-documents-using-the-open-xml-sdk.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think while merging documents CustomXml part data isn't reflecting for databound controls in the final document. I faced a similar issue and my approach was

1. Find the databound controls prior to Merge
2. Assign data to these controls from the CustomXml part
3. Use AltChunk method and Merge

You can find this in method AssignContentFromCustomXmlPartForDataboundControl of OpenXmlHelper class. The code can be downloaded from [Word Document Generator](http://worddocgenerator.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you just need to copy the custom xml parts (and their itemProps related part) into your massive docx document.

From your post, it sounds like altChunk and DocumentBuilder don't do this, but the source code for the latter is available...